# Are there nonaffine schemes over which every exact sequence of vector bundles is split?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, short-exact-sequences

Is there an example of a non-affine scheme $X$ such that every short exact sequence of vector bundles over $X$ splits? If there are such examples then what if we ask it to be true of all (not necessarily finite rank) locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Affine plane with double origin works.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/17316/348986

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/25149/348986

Comment: Punctured affine plane also works.

Comment: @DanPetersen Can you explain why?

Comment: @DanPetersen I don't think that is right? $H^1(\mathbb{A}^2 - \{ 0 \}, \mathcal{O})$ is nonzero, so I think that should mean that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}, \mathcal{O})$ is nonzero on the punctured plane.

Comment: @David You're right - I was assuming the statement would follow from the fact that every vector bundle on $\mathbb A^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is trivial. So your argument shows that there can be a non-split short exact sequence of the form $0 \to \mathcal O \to \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O \to \mathcal O \to 0$ on the punctured affine plane, which is surprising to me. But an example is given by taking the first map to be $f \mapsto (yf,-xf)$ and the second $(g,h) \mapsto gx+hy$.